# c++ time manipulation using time_t in Win platform

Tags: c++, time

Well i want to manipulate time with a time_t variable in this way:

1. time1 = get the current time as time_t (say it's 9:30 now)
2. use SYSTEMTIME to see if we passed 10:00
3. if we didn't pass 10:00 : evaluate what (time_t)time2 would be in 10:00.
   and set time3 = time2 - time1 in order to get in seconds how much is left till 10:00.

I don't want to use boost because i don't want to link my application to it.
I hope i made it clear that i want to check what's the time now and what it would be
in say 10:00 to get the time difference between now and a pre defined time (not date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time_t time1;
time(&time1);

tm time0  = *localtime( &time1);

if (time0.tm_hour == 22 && time0.tm_min == 0)
    ; // it 10PM
else
{
    // force time0 to 10PM
    time0.tm_hour = 22;
    time0.tm_min = 0;
    time_t time2 = mktime(&time0);   
}
```

Comment: BTW, did I get the property names right?  I could find the definition of struct tm on MSDN, so I just guessed based on some examples.

Comment: I think this stack-exchange [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") might be of interest to you. If it is show your support and help get it into beta so you can start poking fun at other people's code! :)

Answer (score 0):

Either use GetSystemTime() so everything is Windows, or call time() to get the current time using the C runtime values.